# Adding two lists while checking length

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

I'm stuck on a question where I have to add 2 lists together while factoring in the length. For example, if `list1 = [1,2]` and `list2 = [3,4,5]` the answer would be `[1+3,2+4,5]` or `[4,6,5]`.

What I have so far is:

```
def addsum(list1,list2):
    new_list = []
    if len(list1) > len(list2):
       new_list = list1[0:]+list2[0:]
```

I'm not really sure how to appraoch this question since I'm new to lists. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools with a `fillvalue` of `0` in a list comprehension:

```
r = [sum(i) for i in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)]
```

`zip_longest` pairs the elements in the input lists (`list1` and `list2` here). If one list is smaller, pairs the remainding elements of the larger list with the value supplied as the `fillvalue` (which we assign to `0` here).

Now, `r` equals:

```
print(r) # [4, 6, 5]
```

Similarly, you could utilize `map` instead of the list-comp:

```
# Python 3.x
r = list(map(sum, zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)))
# Python 2.7
r = map(sum, zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0))
```

and get the same result for `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Poor man's approach:

```
def addsum(list1,list2):
    if len(list1) >= len(list2): 
        for i in range(len(list2)):
            list1[i]=list1[i]+list2[i]
        return list1
    else:
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            list2[i]=list1[i]+list2[i]
        return list2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `zip_longest` solution too, but building in your code this is what I would do

```
def addsum(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) < len(list2):
        list1, list2 = list2, list1
    result=list(list1)
    for i,x in enumerate(list2):
        result[i] += x
    return result
```

first make sure that the first list is the longest, and if that is not the case exchange them, then make a copy of longest list and finally add the elements of the shorter list position-wise to the copy and return it

```
>>> addsum([1,2],[3,4,5])
[4, 6, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `zip_longest` is more neat, another possibility is to use a trial/error approach (if you are tired of "ifs"), as shown here:

```
def addsum(list1, list2):
    res = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(list1) or i < len(list2):
        try:
            res.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
        except IndexError:
            try: res.append(list1[i])
            except IndexError: res.append(list2[i])
        i += 1
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with `fillvalue`. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

Here's the code:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
[x + y for x, y in zip_longest([1,2], [3,4,5], fillvalue=0)]
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 5]
```